# When not to use LINQ To Objects?

Tags: linq-to-objects

When should I **NOT** use LINQ To Objects?

The [inverse of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573539/where-and-when-to-use-linq-to-objects) has been asked, but didn't cover when not to use L2O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is when the performance isn't what you need. If the underlying implementation of `IEnumerable` doesn't have an indexer, calls to `Last(), Skip(), ElementAt()`, etc can result in O(Bad) perf.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, namely:

- No 3.0+
- Performance not a huge concern

However one more to add to the list is the fact that it can cause bad coding practices. A simple (and maybe silly) example is using a `.Distinct()` method too readily. The same applies in SQL, sometimes shortcuts give bad code, which can lead to unknown and damn hard to locate bugs.

I suppose this can happen with anything, but shortcuts can make it easier to code badly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I do't have such choice when programing in projects based on .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing, when:

- You don't have a collection of some data items
- You don't want another collection, formed from the original collection, but after some sort of transformation or filtering. This might be sorting, projection, applying a predicate, grouping, etc.

In resume, when you will not manipulate any kind of group of objects. And also, of course, when you don't have c# 3.0 or above.